# c_across multiple functions per rows with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is it possible to use `rowwise()` and `c_across()` to apply multiple functions in the same c_across statement per rows. With `across()` function we can use the list  of functions per cols, does it work with c_across as well?

```
#sample data
df <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 3, 25, 1),
             b = c(5, 26, 8, 8, 3),
             c = c(9, 10, 11, 11, 12),
             d = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
             e = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 7))


#This will work

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max = max (c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE) ,
         min = min (c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE),
         avg = mean(c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 5 x 8
# Rowwise: 
      a     b     c d         e   max   min   avg
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     5     9 a         1     9     1  4.33
2     2    26    10 b         2    26     2 11.3 
3     3     8    11 c         3    11     3  6.5 
4    25     8    11 d         4    25     4 12.8 
5     1     3    12 e         7    12     1  6  

#This returns errors
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(c_across(where(is.numeric)), 
  list( mean = ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), min = ~min(., na.rm = TRUE),
      max = ~max(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would argue your "This will work" doesn't actually work. When you perform a mutate, it takes into account your previously created columns. I.e., by the time it calculates the mean, it is selects the `min` and `max` columns as well. The mean of columns `a, b, c, e` for row 1 should be 16/4 = 4, not 26/6 = 4.33. But I think I understand what you're getting at...

Admittedly, this feels a little bit hacky but it works (at least on the sample data). `across` is able to take a list of functions because it returns a `tibble`. The aim with this solution is to have it return a `tibble` from a series of `c_across` mutates. Because there's a separation of the original data (`df`), it gives you the mean value at least personally I would expect

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    across(1,
      list( mean = ~mean(c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE),
            min = ~min(c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE),
            max = ~max(c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE)),
      .names = "{.fn}"
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 8
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       a     b     c d         e  mean   min   max
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     9 a         1  4        1     9
#> 2     2    26    10 b         2 10        2    26
#> 3     3     8    11 c         3  6.25     3    11
#> 4    25     8    11 d         4 12        4    25
#> 5     1     3    12 e         7  5.75     1    12
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Because the functions provided all ignore the actual columns selected in (i.e. the use `c_across(where(is.numeric))` to determine relevant columns instead of columns provided by across, you can use any **single**, valid column as the first argument to `across`. The key is to provide only one column so that the functions are only calculated once. I used column 1 as it is usually a safe bet to assume your data.frame has at least one column.

Comment: yes, you are right, "This will work" doesn't actually work. I overlooked it, I must calculates the mean first to avoid selecting min and max columns